# Failed to create AWSConfig rule: InvalidParameterValueException: Blank spaces are not acceptable for input parameter: threshold

Tags: terraform, aws-config

I am trying to create an aws config rule for checking that cloudtrail alarms are enabled. I get the following error `Error: Error creating AWSConfig rule: Failed to create AWSConfig rule: InvalidParameterValueException: Blank spaces are not acceptable for input parameter: threshold.` when I run `terraform apply`. I'm not sure what the formatting issue is in the input parameters argument (see `input_parameters`). The apply works if I remove everything except for `metricName` i.e

```
input_parameters = "{\"metricName\":\"CloudTrailConfigChanges\"}"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
resource aws_config_config_rule ensure-log-alarm-exists-for-cloudtrail {
  name = "ensure-log-alarm-exists-for-cloudtrail"
  description = "Checks whether cloudwatch alarm is on for cloudtrail configuration changes"

  source {
    owner = "AWS"
    source_identifier = "CLOUDWATCH_ALARM_SETTINGS_CHECK"
  }
  
  input_parameters = "{\"metricName\":\"CloudTrailConfigChanges\",\"threshold\":1,\"evaluationPeriod\":1,\"period\":300,\"comparisionOperator\":\"GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold\",\"statistic\":\"Sum\"}"
}
```

It seems like there is an issue parsing type ints from json strings: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/773#issuecomment-385454229

I get the same error even with

```
  input_parameters =<<EOF
{
  "metricName":"CloudTrailConfigChanges",
  "threshold":1
}
EOF
```

or

```
input_parameters = jsonencode({"metricName":"CloudTrailConfigChanges","threshold"=1})
```

Converting wrapping the int value in quotes does not work either.

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "ensure-log-alarm-exists-for-cloudtrail" {
  name        = "ensure-log-alarm-exists-for-cloudtrail"
  description = "Checks whether cloudwatch alarm is on for cloudtrail configuration changes"

  source {
    owner             = "AWS"
    source_identifier = "CLOUDWATCH_ALARM_SETTINGS_CHECK"
  }

  input_parameters = jsonencode({
    metricName = "CloudTrailConfigChanges"
    threshold  = "1"
  })
}
```

The code above produces the following error:

```
Unknown parameters provided in the inputParameters:
```

Answer (score 1):

With your examples you're still specifying the threshold as an integer. Try making it a string.

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "ensure-log-alarm-exists-for-cloudtrail" {
  name        = "ensure-log-alarm-exists-for-cloudtrail"
  description = "Checks whether cloudwatch alarm is on for cloudtrail configuration changes"

  source {
    owner             = "AWS"
    source_identifier = "CLOUDWATCH_ALARM_SETTINGS_CHECK"
  }

  input_parameters = jsonencode({
    metricName = "CloudTrailConfigChanges"
    threshold  = "1"
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've updated the question to show the results of your suggestion. It did not fix the issue. Please remove your answer.

Comment: What version of the AWS provider are you using?
I have tested the above config with v3.18.0 and this works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an error like this, and what resolved it for me was to add a condition.  I don't fully understand why this worked and why it caused this error without the condition, but I saw the condition used in an AWS example.

For example, I first tried using something straightforward like this to reference a parameter:

```
        "InputParameters": {
            "appNames": {
                "Ref": "ApplicationNames"
            }
        }
```

When my resource referenced the ApplicationNames parameter directly like this, it was giving that error.  But using `Conditions` and referencing the parameter this way caused it to work, as in this full template example:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Just a stripped-down example",
    "Parameters": {
        "ApplicationNames": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "This Has Spaces",
            "MinLength": "1",
            "ConstraintDescription": "This parameter is required."
        }
    },
    "Conditions": {
        "ApplicationNamesDefined": {
            "Fn::Not": [
                {
                    "Fn::Equals": [
                        "",
                        {
                            "Ref": "ApplicationNames"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "SampleRule": {
            "Type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",
            "DependsOn": "SecurityHubCustomUpdaterFunction",
            "Properties": {
                "ConfigRuleName": "TheName",
                "Description": "It was here that I was getting 'Blank spaces are not acceptable for input parameter: applicationNames' before I added the Conditions and Fn::If to reference it",
                "InputParameters": {
                    "appNames": {
                        "Fn::If": [
                            "ApplicationNamesDefined",
                            {
                                "Ref": "ApplicationNames"
                            },
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Scope": {
                    "ComplianceResourceTypes": [
                        "AWS::SSM::ManagedInstanceInventory"
                    ]
                },
                "Source": {
                    "Owner": "AWS",
                    "SourceIdentifier": "EC2_MANAGEDINSTANCE_APPLICATIONS_REQUIRED"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you may want to try with `Conditions` usage.